# Formula to count blank cells since the last cell entry in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

To try to make this as simple as possible, I have a table for tracking some information for a game I play. An example of the table I have is attached.

Essentially, what I want to do is have the column Strike Count tally the data entries the way it is, BUT if there is 10 columns in a row without any entries, reset that sum back to 0, and start the counting all over with the next added data point.

The formula I have existing is this:

`=IF(SUMIF(C2:BX2,"<>",C2:BX2)=0,"30 Days Strike Free",SUMIF(C2:BX2,"<>",C2:BX2))`

And that is pulled down the entire column.

If this is not a possible function to create, totally understand. Thanks in advance for the help!

`=IF(SUMIF(C3:BW3,"<>",C3:BW3)=0,"30 Days Strike Free",IF(AND(SUMIF(C3:BW3,"<>",C3:BW3)>0,(COUNTA($B$1:$D$1)-MAX(IF($B2:$D2<>"",COLUMN($B2:$D2)-COLUMN($A2),"")))>9),"30 Days Strike Free"),SUMIF(C3:BW3,"<>",C3:BW3))`

I tried this formula based on some other articles I had found, but frankly got myself way too confused trying to correct it lol

[image]

Link to the spreadsheet screenshot for reference.

Comment: I don't see your example. You can upload images to http://imgur.com and link to them. Someone with enough reputation will likely embed them for you

Comment: Completely did not realize it did not include my picture. Thank you for letting me know, I have edited my post to include the Imgur link

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with a helper row, hope it helps.

Assuming the count is in C2:BX2, you can write below formula in cell C3, the formula records the number of "Strike Free" days, but when a strike happens, the count resets to 0

```
=SCAN(0,C2:BX2,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v="",a+1,0)))
```

[image: blank cells count]

Then in Cell C4, write below:

```
=IF(C3<10,C2,0)
```

Then in Cell D4, write below formula, and drag to BX4:

```
=IF(D3<10,D2+C4,0)
```

This formula keeps a running count of strikes, but if the running count of "Strike Free" hit 10, this number will reset to 0.

I believe the number in cell BX4 is the final "Strike Tally" you are after.